# i got a error when i connect react native apk to node server

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, axios

i want to post data in my api
in local all requestes work properly but when i build apk file this my app give network error

```
 dispatch(CreateUser({ email, name, password })).then((e) => {
        // e.payload.success &&
        navigation.navigate('Verify')
    }).catch((e) => {
        Alert.alert(JSON.stringify(e))
    })
```

this is redux tool kit

```
export const CreateUser = createAsyncThunk(
'CreateUser',
async (body) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.post(server + "api/v1/register", body)
        return response.data
    } catch (err) {
        // console.log(err.response.data)
        return err
    }
  

}
)
```

and in backend i use this

```
const allowedOrigins = ['http://localhost:3000', 'http://localhost:8080'];

app.use(cors({
  origin: allowedOrigins,
}));
```